# Implementation differences between Translation and AntiCorruption layers

Tags: domain-driven-design

1. Conceptually, I understand the difference between *Translation* and *AntiCorruption layers*, but as far as implementation is concerned, is the difference between the two that with *Translation layer* we don't have a *Facade*, nor *Service(s)* residing within *Translation layer* nor do we have an *Adapter*, but instead *domain code itself* ( residing within *Bounded Context* ) calls a *Translator*?
2. a. If *external system* **ES** is actually *part of another application* and offers functionality ( which our *Bounded Context* **BC** needs ) via *its Application layer* and directly from *its Domain layer*, how should our **BC** request the *services it needs*? By communicating with **ES's** *Application layer* or by communicating ( via *Translation/AntiCorruption layer* ) with **ES's** *Domain layer*?

   b. Why isn't *Translation/AntiCorruption layer* also needed when our **BC** requests functionality via **ES's** *Application layer*, since the *data it receives* via **ES's** *Application layer* still needs to be translated into *domain concepts*?

   c. If **ES** is actually part of *our own application*, then I assume only option is for *our* **BC** to request the functionality by communicating "directly" with **ES's** *domain layer* via *Translation/AntiCorruption layer*?

Answer (score 3):

1. Translation is what the ACL does. These aren't separate concepts. Implementation can be done in various ways. The point though is to protect your domain from external systems. The ACL does this by translating the external system's model to your local domain model.

2a. The local BC should communicate with an external BC either through the application service or through an open-host service, which is basically a web service. The former approach is only feasible if you the two BCs are developed in tandem and you have direct libraries that implement both. The latter applies to 3rd party BCs or BCs that are fully encapsulated by the service.

2b. This does still need to happen, unless the two BCs are developed in tandem and have a shared kernel. I'm not a huge fan of shared kernel however.

2c. Your BC still needs to communicate with ES via ES's application service. It should never go directly to domain objects. Better yet, have the ES functionality exposed by web service which BC would call.

Comment: One question about the ACL. ACL is translating between domain models of the external* bounded context and our own bounded context (*external* as in defined in another .dll within the solution).To be able to translate, our ACL will still have to have a reference to the external systems model, in order to correctly access all the object properties and then translate. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?